# how to use @types/node in node application

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, definitelytyped

I am working in VSCode on Ubuntu 16.04. I've created node project using below commads:

```
npm init
tsc --init
```

I've created a new file called **index.ts**. I'm trying to use ***fs and readling*** to read file contents. but when I am writing below lines of code at the top of **index.d.ts**:

```
import fs = require('fs');
import readline =  require('readline');
```

I'm getting below error:
**can not find module 'fs'** and **can not find module 'readline'**

even **process** is not found.
I've installed typings of node from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) using below command:

```
sudo npm install @types/node -global --save
```

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this error?

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?   I think only the (still prelease) typescript 2 supports this approach, so the best answer depends on the version you want to use.

Comment: Typescript: 1.8.10, npm:3.10.3, node: v6.6.0.

Comment: @Burt_Harris, I have to add ///<reference path="" /> ?

Comment: You could probably do it that way, but `npm` doesn't make it easy under 1.8... complicated path to find the right require.   `typings` makes this much easier.

Comment: @Burt_Harris Just out of curiosity why then "import fs from 'fs';" breaks with error **[ts] Module '"fs"' has no default export.**?

Comment: "default exports" are special, and not present in that module.   Use either "import * as fs from 'fs';" or "import fs = require('fs')".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *TypeScript* 1.8, it might be better to `typings` to install the node types.   For detail see the quickstart at: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html.

Answer (score 17):

Since TypeScript 2.x, all typings are installed using `npm` like this: `npm install @types/node`.

Comment: Linking a different question with similar keywords: "When should I install "@types/node" package?" "It seems like VSCode automatically has it installed" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580624/should-i-install-types-node-it-seems-like-vscode-automatically-has-it-installe

Answer (score 0):

For what i know you have two options here:

1. (Recommended) Install devDepencencie `npm install @types/node --save-dev`, which will add the type module for http.
2. Create a `index.d.ts` file declaring a definition for http module, like: 
   `declare module 'http`. This method will not enable auto-complete for http methods