# Should I install @types/node? It seems like VSCode automatically has it installed

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I saw a lot of people installing `@types/node` in their dev dependencies.

However, if you open an empty folder in VSCode, and create an empty js file, and then you type:

```js
const fs = require('fs'); // <= hover it and type shows!
```

Why is this happening? Does VSCode automatically have it installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with **TypeScript**, you must manually manage these types packages. This is required because types are part of the TypeScript compile process, so they are treated like real dependencies

For **JavaScript** however, in most cases the types are only used to offer improved IntelliSense. VS Code often can infer which types packages to download by looking at the `import` statements and `require` calls in code and will then download these types using [automatic type acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition). With automatic type acquisition, you do not need to install anything and your local node_modules is never modified.

If automatic type acquisition does not kick in for some reason, you can always install the types manually.

See the [VS Code JS IntelliSense documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_intellisense) for more details